# C# Stream read in a constant loop

Tags: c#

Using c#, I would like to make a loop where it repeats the task only after the function before completes. Here's my code

```
TcpListener serv = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 19148);
serv.Start();
TcpClient clie = serv.AcceptTcpClient();
NetworkStream stre = clie.GetStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
f1.Show();
f1.TopMost = true;
///the code to repeat starts here
stre.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Enter Message: "), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount("Enter Message: "));
stre.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
f1.label1.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
///ends here
```

I have read up on loops but every time I use one it crashes my program.

I have tried most things, but the most promising one so far has been this but it only shows the form on the last input.

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 3)
{
    stre.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Enter Message: "), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount("Enter Message: "));
    stre.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    f1.label1.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
    i++;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as I have no leads to even point me in the right direction.

Comment: What is `stre` in the code? Please show the relevant code!

Comment: That is now shown in my post

Comment: did you try putting `Form.Show` before the loop?

Comment: Yes it is but I must have pasted the code in wrongly.

Comment: What is your question? Can you formalize better what to you want to achieve?

Comment: Also, you generally should not wait for any kind of IO in a loop in a UI thread: that will freeze your program.

Comment: Move your stream read loop to a backgroundworker, and have it send messages to your main form (So it can update it's label1)

Comment: By the way, you should avoid using `TopMost` on a form as it force your form to stay above other application which might be annoying. And if you really want to have such option, then it should be optional (the user can enable it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to move the read to it's own thread (or use Async methods).  You called `.Show` on the form, but the actual show isn't instantaneous, and it needs the thread you are using for your input to be able to draw itself.  If you absolutely can't move your read loop to another thread (Async, BackgroundWorker, Task, etc), you could change your code to the following:

```
TcpListener serv = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 19148);
serv.Start();
TcpClient clie = serv.AcceptTcpClient();
NetworkStream stre = clie.GetStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
f1.Show();
f1.Refresh(); // Do it RIGHT NOW!
f1.TopMost = true;
int i = 0;
while(i < 3)
{
    stre.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Enter Message: "), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount("Enter Message: "));
    stre.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    f1.label1.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
    f1.label1.Refresh(); // Do it right now!
    i++;
}
```

You will find that your form will display, but it is absolutely frozen.  You can't resize it, it won't repaint itself until your loop finishes.  Not a very good experience.

Comment: Thankyou, this is perfect. I am going to be accessing this remotely so I will be able to implement a quit function with any luck.

Comment: As mentioned, although it works, it should be avoided in real applications... as it make the UI less responsive.